# Python Interactive Window Font

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the font family shown in the new python interactive window that is produced when using the Python extension in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to achieve this is by zooming in or out the entire VS Code window with View -> Appearance -> Zoom In/Zoom Out or use the `Cmd` + `+` or `Cmd` + `-` shortcuts (CTRL instead of Cmd on Windows). Do that until you get the desirable font size on the Python Interactive window.

Of course zooming in or out will change the Python interactive window and the editor font size, but you can go to Settings and increase or decrease the font size of the editor until it becomes around same size as the Python Interactive window font size.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround, I'm putting it for other users:

1. Have "Custom UI" extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui

2. Add custom styleheet to increase editor font size:
   "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
   ".view-line": "font-size: 18px"
   }
3. Zoom out whole window : Cmd + -

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the integrated terminal (which is actually a command shell for whichever operating system you're using, not just for Python), then you are looking for the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` setting in your `settings.json` file. For example, you could use the following line:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Consolas",
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, John!

Unfortunately, the integrated terminal is not what I'm referencing. The latest update of the Python extension for VSCode introduced the ability to run code interactively in a cell-based environment based on Jupyter notebooks rather than having to run the entire script at once. 

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_jupyter-code-cells

The screenshots in the above link show a Python Interactive window whose font matches that of the editor which is what I'm trying to achieve as well.

Comment: IT IS NOT REFERRING TO THE TERMINAL. It is "Python Interactive". A sample screenshot is here: https://imgur.com/XiHuPal . The default font size on the Python Interactive panel is so small and that is so irritating.